# How do I configure network interface and default gateway in CentOS?

Tags: networking, dns, centos

I set enp0s3 interface address with a command:

```
ifconfig enp0s3 192.168.1.100
```

Next I used following commmand to set default gateway:

```
route add default gw 192.168.1.1 enp0s3
```

and it works.

How do i write configuration to /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s3 for persistence over reboots?

How do I configure DNS to make following command work:

```
ping superuser.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DEVICE=enp0s3
BOOTPROTO=static
BROADCAST=192.168.1.255
IPADDR=192.168.1.100
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
GATEWAY=192.168.1.1
DNS1=1.1.1.1
DNS2=8.8.8.8
ONBOOT=yes`

read through `man 5 ifcfg` or https://wiki.centos.org/FAQ/CentOS7

Comment: Additionally how do I set DNS without config file?

Comment: DNS could be included as in example or you could define in /etc/resolv.conf: `nameserver 1.1.1.1` one parameter per line